# Combing two large data frames based on conditions in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas

My first data frame has various columns one of which contains a Practice ID column and my second data frame has various columns one of which contains practice No so I have found the link between the two. However how can I link these together using the Practice number to assign the postcode information from data frame 2 to the correct practice in data frame 1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Date frame 1

```
ID  Practice Items Cost
0      5     10  2001.00
1     12     2  20.98
2      2     4  100.80
3      7     7  199.60
```

Data frame 2

```
ID  Prac No  Dr      Postcode
0      1     Dr.K     BT94 7HX
1      5     Dr.H     BT7 4MC
2      3     Dr.Love  BT9 1HE
3      7     Dr.Kerr  BT72 4TX
```

I want to create a new column 'Postcode' in Data frame 1 and assign the postcode to the correct Practice

```
ID  Practice Items Cost Postcode      
0      5         10  BT7 4MC
1      3          3  BT9 1HE
2      22         8  BT62 4TU
3      7          7  BT72 4TX
```

How can I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a `merge` + a little cleanup.

```
df = df1.merge(df2[['Prac No', 'Postcode']], 
         left_on='Practice', right_on='Prac No').drop('Prac No', 1)

df  # for this data

   ID  Practice  Items    Cost  Postcode
0   0         5     10  2001.0   BT7 4MC
1   3         7      7   199.6  BT72 4TX
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thank you so much this has really helped!!